# Eclipse start with previously set (un)folded methods

Tags: eclipse

I frequently use folding/unfolding of methods in Eclipse for Java while working. However after each launch of Eclipse I need to redo the settings of folding/unfolding methods. Is it possible to make the framework "remember" my settings in each opened file? By folding/unfolding I meen clicking (+)/(-) button as on the following picture:

[image]

Please note I do not want all methods to be folded or all to be unfolded. I want the fremwork to remember my settings.

Answer (score 0):

Although `Eclipse` doesn't natively support the remembering of folding/collapsed state of its editors, you can use external plugin to do the same. Here's a plugin that might help you with your problem.

[Eclipse Folding Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-folding-plugin#group-details)

Comment: How can I install it? I do not see it in Marketplace of my Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 2)